# Debian xarchiver "Failed to execute child process "ar" (No such file or directory)"

Tags: debian, package-management, xfce, ar

I have Debian 9 and Xfce. am trying to install a commercial program given as a .deb -ending file. When I double click on the file, it opens a window titled "(filename.deb) - Xarchiver 0.5.4" and on top of that a pop-up error message

```
Can't run the archiver executable:
Failed to execute child process "ar" (No such file or directory)
```

Is `ar` a command I'm missing? I tried on a terminal `sudo apt-get install ar` and the response is `E: Unable to locate package ar`

A similar problem seems to be in
[KDE opens .deb files with ar instead of a package manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199774/344355)
but their context is KDE, not Xfce.

Comment: `/usr/bin/ar` is provided by `binutils`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing `ar` won’t help; what you need to do is install the package you have. Since you mention using a terminal, use that:

```
cd /path/to/directory/containing/filename.deb
sudo apt install ./filename.deb
```

If you’d rather use a graphical tool, install `gdebi` first, then run that (from your launcher, or `gdebi-gtk` from the terminal); this is the Gtk variant of the `gdebi-kde` tool mentioned in [KDE opens .deb files with ar instead of a package manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/199774/86440), and is appropriate for Xfce.

Comment: It might be worth, given the question, expanding upon the relationship between `gdebi-gtk` and `gdebi-kde` from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/199928/5132 .

Comment: Indeed @JdeBP, I’ve updated my answer, thanks.